# Problem with geometry checker plugin

Tags: geometry, topology

I've used Geometry Checker Plugin to find some errors in my work. I have points that are connected to each other by lines.
Among the parameters entered in the plugin there is "point covered by line".
Unfortunately the result that gives me QGIS is that all the points are not covered by lines ... 
but most of the points I have are actually covered.

Why does Geometry Checker return these errors to me?

Here is an image of Geometry Checker Plugin window
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not any Line type vector layer selected, the plugin does not find any lines that cover the points.

The option should probably be disabled in this case.

Select the line layer by which the points must be covered so that they are not selected for that reason.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your reply. To select the line level that interests me, is it correct to flag both the input parameters (in the "input vectors" part?)
Is it necessary to flag "Solo geometrie selezionate"?
I tried to launch the plugin with this settings and in this case it gives me zero errors, and this is equally unlikely ... I don't know maybe I'm wrong in the parameters?

Comment: @eugenio1987, You are welcome. Yes, both Point and Line type vector layers must be selected as input parameters. You can also select some features of the layers and check the geometries of those features with the "Just selected geometries" option. If you enable that option without any feature selected, the plugin is not checking any geometry.